# How to get Linux to display hidden files beginning with b?

Tags: ls, file-management

I am currently taking a Controlled Assessment in a Computing GCSE and this is the task.

> At the command prompt, type ls -a. Demonstrate and explain what
>   happens. Modify this command so that it only shows hidden files
>   beginning with the letter ‘b’.

I have already done `ls -a` and I tried `ls -b`, but it didn't work.

Comment: `ls -a | grep .b*` should do I think

Comment: that's good. Please set my answer below as approved then :)

Comment: @ddnomad `grep`ing an `ls` output is unnecessarily complex, when you can specify the pattern with `ls -a -d .b*` - note that you need `-d` for not listing contents of the results. Also that `grep` will show files like `123.bWRONG`.

Comment: All the information you need is in `man ls`. I suggest you read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names of hidden files start with `.` (dot), there are none that start with `b`.  To list names starting with `.b` use

```
$ ls .b*
```

This will also list the contents of any directory whose name starts with `.b`. Note that `-a` is not needed here as we explicitly give a filename pattern for the shell to match. Since the pattern starts with `.` (dot), it will match hidden files. The expanded pattern will be given to `ls` for processing.

To avoid listing the contents of directories, use

```
$ ls -d .b*
```

The above solutions will give an error if no name matches the pattern.

To only list the names of *regular files* whose names start with `.b`, use

```
$ for name in .b*; do test -f "$name" && printf '%s\n' "$name"; done
```

To get the output in a similar way as with plain `ls` (note that `column` is a non-standard utility):

```
$ for name in .b*; do test -f "$name" && printf '%s\n' "$name"; done | column
```

The last couple of solutions will not print anything of no name matches the pattern.

Comment: When worrying about file type `regular`, a `find` command would be much simpler: `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.b*'`. Also faster than a `for` loop. However, I assume `ls`-usage was intended.

Comment: @Fiximan If your `find` is able to do it that way, of course. Standard `find` needs a search path, and doesn't understand `-maxdepth`. This will also generate output with `./` prepended to the name (with GNU `find`).

Comment: I was aware of the implied `.` serach path being a GNU `find` variation, but not that even `-maxdepth` is, since BSD `find` had it (see [man find](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) )- good to know!

Comment: @Fiximan See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html

Answer (score 4):

`ls` is the command, and `-a` is the flag for the command.
In order to see the files staring from `b` one can specify a pattern - `.b*`
Where `.` means that the files are hidden and the `*` means everything else...

and in general when you don't know what a command does, read the manual - `man ls`

For avoiding listing of the contents of the listed items, use the `-d` option.